# Instantiating Spring MVC controllers like ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spring.net

The biggest advantage of ASP.NET MVC is that creating new controllers/views is as simple as creating classes in the appropriate namespaces.

On the contrary, Spring MVC leverages the Spring `Context` to enable instantiating controllers from just anywhere. In my case, I just need the *existing controllers* in my *existing project* to be instantiated by the simplemost Spring factory that can autowire a few services in my context.

I'm doing this migration/maintenance step by step, so now I want to ask how to avoid the following error

```
IControllerFactory 'Spring.Web.Mvc.SpringControllerFactory' returned no controller for name 'Upload'.
```

(i.e. `Upload` is my default controller in route settings)

How can I tell Spring to initialize controllers like ASP.NET does? It's a dozen controllers, I could wire them into the XML context but I prefer autodetection

Comment: Maybe i don't get it well, you don't want to use component-scan?

Comment: I just don't want to type 10+ "<object" tags but I haven't yet found documentation for the equivalent of Java's "<context:component-scan". Component scan is a great idea